# Merging mercurial repo after lfconvert

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-extension

I want to use the largefiles extension to track binary data in my repos.
[The documentation](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/LargefilesExtension) states that you have to convert your "normal" repo to a "largefiles" repo.
Like so:

```
hg lfconvert normal_repo largefiles_repo
```

Is it possible to merge two repos after they have been converted to a largefiles repo without both of this repos to have been converted at the some "time".
Or do all repos have to share a common "lfconvert event" to be able to merge between them?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like lfconvert rewrites repository history from the point where the first large file appears. You could theoretically merge the resulting repo in your old repo, but then the (versions of) large files you had in your old repository will also be in the merged repository; you will end up with a repository sporting two roots.