# Is it possible to convert a googlecode hg repository to a largefile repository?

Tags: mercurial, google-code

I have a remote hg repository hosted on googlecode. Thus I don't have admin access to run e.g. `lfconvert` on it (as far as I know), and of course `lfconvert` can only be used on local repositories.

So, is there any way to a convert an googlecode hg repository to a largefile repository?

(one idea is to convert a local clone of the repo to a largefile repo and then push the changes to the "central" googlecode repo, but I fear trying that without knowing if it is a valid approach).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your idea to do a local conversion and push, you can take advantage of the 'reset' feature for your repositories:

1. Do a local clone.
2. Convert to largefiles: `hg lfconvert normal_repo largefiles_repo``. **Do NOT delete the original clone until you are sure everything works.**
3. Reset the hosted repository (See https://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/MercurialFAQ#Mercurial_FAQ).
4. Push the largefiles repository.

Pushing the largefiles repository without reseting seems problematic because the largefiles repository is [essentially a fork of the original one starting at the point the first largefile was committed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13932034/2022326).

If the push fails*, you can push the original clone and you'll be back where you started without any data loss. (One of the many advantages of DVCS. :-))

The big downside of course is that everybody who has ever cloned your project will now be working from a different fork of the repository. This is always a danger when you do anything involving changing history and is the motivation for [Mercurial phases](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Phases). If you want to be 'kinder', you can start a second project for the largefiles version and place a link at the original project cite describing the move.

[*] I can't figure out from Google Code's documentation whether the largefiles extension is supported. There is a [reviewed feature request](https://code.google.com/p/support/issues/detail?id=5975), but I couldn't find any mention of the request actually being implemented. The push failing would probably be a good indication that largefiles isn't supported though...

Comment: Thanks @Livius for your excellent, detailed answer: great idea. Unfortunately, it does not work: I get "abort: <googlecode repo> does not appear to be a largefile store" when trying to push the lfconverted to the reset googlecode repo. So it seems googlecode simply doesn't support largefile repos at this time (I commented on the issue you linked to to see if I could get a status update from them).

Comment: Unfortunately, @StephenSwensen, I  don't see largefile support coming anytime soon to any of the major (free) hosting services. Besides the implicit encouragement of storing large amounts of data, it also fundamentally changes the way the repo is stored and transferred (which is why it's a [Feature of Last Resort](http://bit.ly/N5LcZf).) Making the standard way of doing things (a single OS-level user account and trickery with ssh keys) play nice with a largefiles cache across so many repos and 'lightweight' users seems non trivial, esp. given the security concerns of a shared store.